# Twilio Fax line check with Voice API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

My bad if this question has been raised before or out of normality bounds. I have a fax machine and without sending an actual fax, I want to ensure the fax machine is up and running.

Having used twilio voice rest api, i tired to call the fax number and got the following status

- ringing
- in-progress
- completed

Is in-progress status an acknowledgement from fax machine that it connected with the call? or is there an better way to ensure?

the fax machine emits sound https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnR03_10ai4

```
tclient = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
cinstance = tclient.calls.create(to=FAX_NUMBER, from_=TW_NUMBER, url=FAX_TWIML)
while True:
     print(cinstance.fetch().status)
     if cinstance.fetch().status == 'completed':
        break
```

Comment: I don't know of anyone else who is using Twilio for this! You might be right that when it connects, that means the fax is online. Can you test with failure states and see how far Twilio gets through the call as well?

Comment: Thanks philnash for your comment, I will check the fail scenario and update the question

Comment: Hi Philnash, I was able to test with failure states, I have fax servers in my company and when that was down for maintenance, twilio gave me the status 'ringing -> busy' when i dialed the fax number. Whats your take on this?

Comment: I would actually recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and explaining the issue. It doesn't sound right to me that you'd get a busy signal if the machine is just not present.

Comment: Thanks philnash, I will do that